# How should I design a class structure for an application such that the UI is updated asynchronously

Tags: c#, wpf

*(disclaimer: I'm brand new to c#, just trying to figure it out)*

Is there a 'best practice' when interacting with a UI from multiple threads? I've seen some people suggest `Invoke` from each data loader, but others suggest that data gathering threads should notify the UI thread in some way, and rely on that thread to update the UI appropriately.  I kinda prefer the latter, so would it be better to have a shared list of objects and a loop in the drawing thread that displays and removes any in this list? Or another idea I like is to have methods of the containing control (or top level window) such as `NotifyDoneGatheringUserList(List<string> names` and `NotifyDoneGatheringUserData(User user)`, so the gathering threads wouldn't need to know anything about the shared object idea; if this is practical, is there a `System.Window.GetMainWindow()` style of function, or would I need/want to pass in the object each time i spawn a gatherer like `new Thread(GetUserDataFromUser(user, this))`

To illustrate:

**Invoke**

```
public MainWindow()
{
  new Thread(GetUsers());

public void GetUsers()
{
  List<string> users;
  <load users here>
  mainWindow.Invoke((delegate){userList.Text = users.ToString()});
}
```

**Shared Object**

```
public MainWindow()
{
  new Thread(GetUsers());
  // somehow start a look to handle UI updates here without blocking...have to investigate.
}

private Loop() 
{
  while (true)
  {
      lock(sharedList);
      if (!sharedList.empty())
      {
          userList.Text += sharedList.Front().ToString();
          sharedList.PopFront();
      }
      sharedList.Unlock();
      Sleep(50);
  }
}


// data gathering class

public void GetUsers()
{
  List<string> users;
  <load users here>
  lock(mainWindow.sharedList);
  mainWindow.sharedList.Push(users)
  unlock(mainWindow.sharedList);
}
```

**Exposed methods**

```
public MainWindow()
{
  new Thread(GetUsers());
  // somehow start a look to handle UI updates here without blocking...have to investigate.
}

private Loop()
{
  while (true)
  {
      lock(sharedList);
      if (!sharedList.empty())
      {
          userList.Text += sharedList.Front().ToString();
          sharedList.PopFront();
      }
      sharedList.Unlock();
      Sleep(50);
  }
}

public void NotifyUsersLoaded(List<string> users)
{
  lock(this.sharedList);
  this.sharedList.Push(users)
  unlock(thissharedList);
}


// data gathering class

public void GetUsers()
{
  List<string> users;
  <load users here>
  mainWindow.NotifyUsersLoaded(users)
}
```

Comment: Have a look at BackgroundWorker class, this allows async processing with synchronized process update/completion events, or even the Async/Await pattern could fit your scenario

Comment: OR fire off a thread and handle the update by trigger of a custom event in that thread in your other class - and hook a handler to that custom event in the UI thread.

Comment: `Is there a 'best practice'` - Yes, it's called MVVM. Please research on this if you're starting with WPF. It's going to simplify your code and your life a `lot`.

Answer (score 0):

In my personal opinion, it's all much simpler than that. You are correct in thinking that (in general) we update the UI using the UI thread. As for fetching data and implementing long running functionality, we don't really need to continually create new threads, particularly not `new Thread()`... using the `Thread` class directly is a bit 'old fashioned' now in .NET.

It's much easier to use asynchronous `delegate`s with call back handlers, or if you're using .NET 4.5, it's even easier using the great new `await` keyword. If you don't know about these, take a look at the following links:

[Asynchronous Programming Using Delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22t547yb.aspx)

[Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx)

When using these methods, you don't need to 'notify' the UI thread when work is done... either you have a call back handler for your `delegate`, or your method just continues after the `await` keyword... nice and easy.

One last thing to note when writing asynchronous WPF applications is that in the UI, you *might* want to set the `IsAsync` property of the `Binding` class to `True` on your data bound controls... basically, this just avoids blocking the UI while the data is being fetched.

Comment: I did come across the async/await keywords in my research, but the examples given didn't seem to demonstrate multiple async events coming from a single handler. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh696703.aspx is close, but those require all to finish before anything is done. Say I have 3 data gatherers attached in an event handler - I start by showing 'loading...' in all 3 boxes, and then attempt to load all 3 (presumably multi-threaded is faster here?). As soon as any completes, it updates the corresponding control.  I'll have a look at the delegates though -thanks!